# Error when creating a data frame in Python: ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure there's a simple fix but can't seem to figure it out! I've built a linear regression model and want to print a data frame of predicted and actual values. The code I've used is:

`pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': predictions})`

But I get the error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

y_test is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and has shape (107, 1). [image]

predictions is a `numpy.ndarray` and is like

```
array([[414.29948336],
       [272.64376115],
       [150.80159973],
       [311.40257489],
       [369.62096393],
       [ 56.11742083],
       [229.75138275],
       [349.64883928],
       [712.30190763],
       [290.90705568],
       [380.94372689],
       [222.3002812 ],
       [433.96730488],
       [165.3781886 ],
       [250.98783721],
       [440.33255787],
       [138.09360886],
       [126.55234018],
       [195.51347947],
       [191.3026039 ],
       [144.20365538],
       [170.74315144],
       [ 74.17045713],
       [279.72135584],
       [485.45758961],
       [196.70740154],
       [244.7141134 ],
       [-58.89209287],
       [233.43393998],
       [ 56.47082062],
       [277.27274513],
       [ 61.97442991],
       [247.48593027],
       [507.90630021],
       [350.02432551],
       [225.39910598],
       [126.98126116],
       [ 51.21470666],
       [600.03422356],
       [208.68433733],
       [273.42139716],
       [207.37800368],
       [420.99190128],
       [149.96541554],
       [293.02097997],
       [202.8281036 ],
       [ 51.08671574],
       [331.59103622],
       [ 74.46627376],
       [111.4738575 ],
       [ 53.4787083 ],
       [389.50136975],
       [268.12362603],
       [117.19361381],
       [269.55206181],
       [ 67.67426883],
       [192.92940572],
       [530.2434072 ],
       [273.68760586],
       [358.61944448],
       [180.66947787],
       [296.59209063],
       [201.75507963],
       [287.69464791],
       [143.94472916],
       [212.23890366],
       [212.3128415 ],
       [ 51.96273474],
       [375.57322194],
       [259.59519506],
       [ 31.58888898],
       [183.43835035],
       [319.96021775],
       [ 76.13864214],
       [136.27178145],
       [ 64.19011025],
       [353.24893954],
       [541.79947984],
       [151.29364598],
       [239.88614506],
       [ 51.08671574],
       [ 51.96273474],
       [496.12993212],
       [109.60584519],
       [411.2082127 ],
       [206.19256811],
       [149.36176568],
       [114.82153866],
       [456.05257846],
       [558.65859408],
       [129.50973114],
       [181.63009025],
       [129.11510285],
       [525.34995489],
       [378.97554187],
       [433.13960719],
       [470.56309767],
       [434.11087511],
       [555.39906903],
       [262.61846603],
       [435.89348605],
       [ 90.78858316],
       [183.48450262],
       [188.12705391],
       [391.71193665],
       [175.70224474],
       [351.82112208]])
```

Anyone got any ideas/help? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add a small sample of `ytest`?

Comment: Added a screenshot! Think it's just a data frame?

Comment: Check with `pd.DataFrame({'Actual': list(y_test['n_for_sale']), 'Predicted': predictions.squeeze()})`